# Remove a 'where' clause from an ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class method on User, that returns applies a complicated select / join / order / limit to User, and returns the relation. It also applies a `where(:admin => true)` clause. Is it possible to remove this one particular `where` statement, if I have that relation object with me?

Something like

```
User.complex_stuff.without_where(:admin => true)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this (`where_values` holds each `where` query; you'd have to tweak the SQL to match the exact output of `:admin => true` on your system). Keep in mind this will only work if you haven't actually executed the query yet (i.e. you haven't called `.all` on it, or used its results in a view):

```
@users = User.complex_stuff
@users.where_values.delete_if { |query| query.to_sql == "\"users\".\"admin\" = 't'" }
```

However, I'd strongly recommend using Emily's answer of restructuring the `complex_stuff` method instead.

Answer (score 38):

I know this is an old question, but since rails 4 now you can do this

```
User.complex_stuff.unscope(where: :admin)
```

This will remove the where admin part of the query, if you want to unscope the whole `where` part unconditinoally

```
User.complex_stuff.unscope(:where)
```

ps: thanks to @Samuel for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 10):

I haven't found a way to do this. The best solution is probably to restructure your existing `complex_stuff` method.

First, create a new method `complex_stuff_without_admin` that does everything `complex_stuff` does except for adding the `where(:admin => true)`. Then rewrite the `complex_stuff` method to call `User.complex_stuff_without_admin.where(:admin => true)`.

Basically, just approach it from the opposite side. Add where needed, rather than taking away where not needed.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question and this doesn't answer the question per say but [rewhere](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/rewhere) is a thing that exists.

From the documentation:

> Allows you to change a previously set where condition for a given attribute, instead of appending to that condition.

So something like:

```
Person.where(name: "John Smith", status: "live").rewhere(name: "DickieBoy")
```

Will output:

```
SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` WHERE `people`.`name` = 'DickieBoy' AND `people`.`status` = 'live';
```

The key point being that the name column has been overwritten, but the status column has stayed.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this (`Remove a 'where' clause from an ActiveRecord::Relation` which was being created by a scope) while joining two scopes, and did it like this: `self.scope(from,to).values[:joins]`.

I wanted to join values from the two scopes that made up the 'joined_scope' without the 'where' clauses, so that I could add altered 'where' clauses separately (altered to use 'OR' instead of 'AND').

For me, this went in the joined scope, like so:

```
scope :joined_scope, -> (from, to) {
  joins(self.first_scope(from,to).values[:joins])
  .joins(self.other_scope(from,to).values[:joins])
  .where(first_scope(from,to).ast.cores.last.wheres.inject{|ws, w| (ws &&= ws.and(w)) || w}
  .or(other_scope(from,to).ast.cores.last.wheres.last))
}
```

Hope that helps someone